# PHP __call and generate function name

Tags: php

How can I generate function name with `__cal` ?

Example:

```
public function setTitleEn($title){
  $this->titleEn = $title;
}
public function setTitleDe($title){
  $this->titleDe = $title;
}
public function setBodyEn($body){
      $this->bodyEn = $body;
    }
public function setBodyDe($body){
  $this->bodyDe = $body;
}

public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
  //execution function
}

$article = new Article();
$article->setTitle("My title", "en") //execution setTitleEn
$article->setTitle("My title", "de") //execution setTitleDe
$article->setBody("My title", "de") //execution setBodyEn
```

etc.

Comment: `switch ($arguments) { case 'en': $this->setTitleEn(...); }`?

Comment: But its example and I have more functions.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for? http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: `$func = $name . ucfirst($arguments[1]); $this->$func($arguments[0]);`

Comment: @deceze The `ucfirst()` call is not required at all.

Comment: @hjpotter92 But it's arguably a nice touch. :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not necessarily "generating" a method, but you can dynamically call those methods with __call()

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    $method = $name . ucfirst($arguments[1]);
    return $this->$method($arguments[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `call_user_func_array`. You'll have to build some assumptions here, like the fact that the final argument will always be treated as the language.

```
public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    $lang = 'en';
    if (count($arguments) > 1)
        $lang = array_shift($arguments);

    $fname = $name.ucwords($lang);
    if (method_exists($this, $fname) === false) {
        throw new Exception('Method "'.$name.'" does not exist.');
    }

    return call_user_func_array(
        array($this, $fname), 
        $arguments
    );
}
```

**Documentation**

- `call_user_func_array` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php
- `method_exists` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php